# JSON stored in variable has keys added

Tags: javascript, json

I'm issuing an AJAX call from my app to send a JSON message.
I pass this variable to the call:

```
json_msg = {"object":"page", 
            "entry":[
                {"id":"317614815243036",
                  "time":1473615625653, 
                   "messaging":[
                              {"sender":{id":"1142389195826076"},
                               "recipient":{"id":"317614815243036"},        
                               "timestamp":1473615625498, 
                                "message":{
                                            "mid":"mid.1473615625491:99adedcab35dd94768", 
                                            "seq":4741, 
                                            "text":"Hey"
                                           }
                                }]
                }
             ]
          }
```

But when I do a `console.log(json_msg)`, I get this:

```
json_msg = {"object":"page", 
                "entry":[
                    0:{"id":"317614815243036", // A ZERO ADDED HERE
                      "time":1473615625653, 
                       "messaging":[
                                 0: {"sender":{id":"1142389195826076"}, // A ZERO ADDED HERE
                                   "recipient":{"id":"317614815243036"},        
                                   "timestamp":1473615625498, 
                                    "message":{
                                                "mid":"mid.1473615625491:99adedcab35dd94768", 
                                                "seq":4741, 
                                                "text":"Hey"
                                               }
                                    }]
                    }
                 ]
              }
```

There are two "0" keys that are being added straight after assigning the variable (to test, I commented out the call and just logged the variable).

This is surely a stupid mistake but I can't find the origin

Comment: You are missing a `"` around the secound `id`

Comment: Copy error, I'm editing it, it's not in my script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of `console.log` isn't JSON.

It shows the indexes of the array elements. This is normal.

Comment: No it's not JSON it's a javascript object but if I dig into it and click on the object, these keys are there. When issuing the call, same problem. The received JSON has those extra keys

Comment: @GrahamSlick — That's how arrays work. Each member gets an integer property name starting at zero.

Comment: Just try `console.log(JSON.stringify(json_msg, null, 2))` and compare the difference

Comment: @GrahamSlick: Arrays are objects. The first element in an array is assigned to property `0`. The console just shows you **a** representation of the data.

Comment: Ok thanks everyone. I'm more familiar with ruby, which has hashes objects and I don't remember seeing this behavior with hashes so I was confused.

Comment: @Quentin is there a way then to send this object as JSON and have it received without the indexes of the array elements ?

Comment: @GrahamSlick — Arrays can't not have indexes. If you don't want an array, then don't use an array (it isn't like you have multiple elements in the arrays in your code sample). If `0: ` is showing up in your actual JSON (not the result of dumping a JS object through `console.log`), then something is very weirdly wrong with however you are generating the JSON from the JS object (which isn't in the code you've shared with us).